# Определение дружеских связей в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, cluster

У меня появилась, в которой надо определить наличие дружеской связи.
Поясню, на работе стоит пропускной пункт. Сотрудник, проходя через него, попадает в базу, где фиксируется его время и ФИО. Если сотрудник часто проходит через пункт с одним и тем же человеком, то можно считать, что между ними дружеская связь.
Для примера я сделал маленький time Series:

```
    import pandas as pd
dict_df={
    'Data':['2020-02-10 10:00:23','2020-02-10 10:01:23','2020-02-10 10:01:30','2020-02-10 10:01:43',
            '2020-02-10 10:02:02','2020-02-10 10:02:30','2020-02-10 10:02:35','2020-02-10 10:02:50',
            '2020-02-10 10:02:58','2020-02-10 10:03:02','2020-02-10 10:03:10','2020-02-10 10:03:15',
            '2020-02-10 10:03:26','2020-02-10 10:03:32','2020-02-10 10:03:38','2020-02-10 10:03:40',
            '2020-02-10 10:03:46','2020-02-10 10:03:50','2020-02-10 10:04:04','2020-02-10 10:04:12',
            '2020-02-10 10:04:23','2020-02-10 10:04:27','2020-02-10 10:04:45','2020-02-10 10:04:50',
            '2020-02-10 10:04:59','2020-02-10 10:05:20','2020-02-10 10:05:26','2020-02-10 10:05:40',
            '2020-02-10 10:05:56','2020-02-10 10:06:12','2020-02-10 10:06:18','2020-02-10 10:06:30',
            '2020-02-10 10:06:37'],
    'Name':['Ann','Jhon','Chase','Bruce','Evan','Fred','Hugh','Gregory','Jack','Caleb','Eric','James',
            'Ann','Gerld','Jess','Juan','Luke','Kyle','Neil','Owen','James','Eric','Jhon','Jess','Norman',
            'Hugh','Fred','Gregory','Ryan','Angel','Cole','James','Eric']}

df=pd.DataFrame(dict_df)
```

Вот так от выглядит:

```
    Data                Name
0   2020-02-10 10:00:23 Ann
1   2020-02-10 10:01:23 Jhon
2   2020-02-10 10:01:30 Chase
3   2020-02-10 10:01:43 Bruce
4   2020-02-10 10:02:02 Evan
5   2020-02-10 10:02:30 Fred
6   2020-02-10 10:02:35 Hugh
7   2020-02-10 10:02:50 Gregory
8   2020-02-10 10:02:58 Jack
9   2020-02-10 10:03:02 Caleb
10  2020-02-10 10:03:10 Eric
11  2020-02-10 10:03:15 James
12  2020-02-10 10:03:26 Ann
13  2020-02-10 10:03:32 Gerld
14  2020-02-10 10:03:38 Jess
15  2020-02-10 10:03:40 Juan
16  2020-02-10 10:03:46 Luke
17  2020-02-10 10:03:50 Kyle
18  2020-02-10 10:04:04 Neil
19  2020-02-10 10:04:12 Owen
20  2020-02-10 10:04:23 James
21  2020-02-10 10:04:27 Eric
22  2020-02-10 10:04:45 Jhon
23  2020-02-10 10:04:50 Jess
24  2020-02-10 10:04:59 Norman
25  2020-02-10 10:05:20 Hugh
26  2020-02-10 10:05:26 Fred
27  2020-02-10 10:05:40 Gregory
28  2020-02-10 10:05:56 Ryan
29  2020-02-10 10:06:12 Angel
30  2020-02-10 10:06:18 Cole
31  2020-02-10 10:06:30 James
32  2020-02-10 10:06:37 Eric
```

Мне надо, что было так:

```
    Data                Name   cluster
0   2020-02-10 10:00:23 Ann     0
1   2020-02-10 10:01:23 Jhon    0
2   2020-02-10 10:01:30 Chase   0
3   2020-02-10 10:01:43 Bruce   0
4   2020-02-10 10:02:02 Evan    0
5   2020-02-10 10:02:30 Fred    1
6   2020-02-10 10:02:35 Hugh    1
7   2020-02-10 10:02:50 Gregory 1
8   2020-02-10 10:02:58 Jack    0
9   2020-02-10 10:03:02 Caleb   0
10  2020-02-10 10:03:10 Eric    2
11  2020-02-10 10:03:15 James   2
12  2020-02-10 10:03:26 Ann     0
13  2020-02-10 10:03:32 Gerld   0
14  2020-02-10 10:03:38 Jess    0
15  2020-02-10 10:03:40 Juan    0
16  2020-02-10 10:03:46 Luke    0
17  2020-02-10 10:03:50 Kyle    0
18  2020-02-10 10:04:04 Neil    0
19  2020-02-10 10:04:12 Owen    0
20  2020-02-10 10:04:23 James   2
21  2020-02-10 10:04:27 Eric    2
22  2020-02-10 10:04:45 Jhon    0
23  2020-02-10 10:04:50 Jess    0
24  2020-02-10 10:04:59 Norman  0
25  2020-02-10 10:05:20 Hugh    1
26  2020-02-10 10:05:26 Fred    1
27  2020-02-10 10:05:40 Gregory 1
28  2020-02-10 10:05:56 Ryan    0
29  2020-02-10 10:06:12 Angel   0
30  2020-02-10 10:06:18 Cole    0
31  2020-02-10 10:06:30 James   2
32  2020-02-10 10:06:37 Eric    2
```

Можно увидеть, что Fred, Gregory и Hugh проходили несколько раз вместе, значит дружеская связь установлена. Также James и Eric вместе проходили, значит тоже дружеская связь.

Я хочу понять, можно ли ее решить с помощью машинного обучения, скажем кластеризацией.
Подскажите, может у кого есть мысли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что это задача для машинного обучения. А вот решить ее на графе - вполне. Строите нагруженный граф, где каждая вершина - сотрудник, а каждая нагруженная связь - это количество раз, когда они проходили ворота вместе. Потом с этим графом можно работать примерно так, как это делают, когда выявляют связи в социальных сетях. Обнаруживать дружеские коллективы, например. Или влюбленные парочки :-).  Кстати, примерно так в соответствующих прикладных областях выявляют и членов криминальных группировок и аффилированные компании. По нагруженному графу связей, которые правда строятся исходя из другого набора признаков.

Если под кластеризацией вы понимали задачу разбиения графа на связанные компоненты -  то да. А если кластеризация, как она понимается в задачах машинного обучения - то трудно вообразить.  Ну и Датафрейм тут совсем инструмент, а не определяющий фактор задачи.

Comment: @ passant, спасибо большое. Я уже тоже пришел к этом мысли. Посмотрим, что получится)

Comment: @Egor_1811 Обратите внимание: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers